# How to show full xml file in datagirdview c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, dataset

So I have a directory with many XML files. I tried to show dataset in datagirdview but not enough content, someone please help me show all the content in the file
Below is the code and XML I used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:BoardTestXMLExport numberOfIndictedComponents="4" testerTestStartTime="2021-01-18T07:46:32.000+07:00" testTime="2021-01-18T07:46:24.000+07:00" repairStationId="VNHCMING100" testStatus="Repaired" testerTestEndTime="2021-01-18T07:46:37.000+07:00" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/BoardTestXMLExport.xsd" numberOfIndictedPins="0" numberOfComponentsTested="320" numberOfJointsTested="0" numberOfDefects="4" repairStatus="Repaired">
    <ns1:BoardXML imageId="3" serialNumber="21017227600" assemblyRevision="ING-296269012AC-A-B" boardType="ING-296269012AC-A-B" boardRevision="1610927415000"/>
    <ns1:StationXML testerName="HCMINGAOI02" stage="V510"/>
    <ns1:RepairEventXML numberOfVariationOkDefects="0" numberOfFalseCalledPins="0" numberOfRepairedComponents="2" numberOfVariationOkPins="0" numberOfRepairedPins="0" numberOfRepairLaterPins="0" numberOfFalseCalledDefects="2" numberOfActiveDefects="0" numberOfVariationOkComponents="0" repairEndTime="2021-01-18T07:49:24.000+07:00" repairStartTime="2021-01-18T07:49:10.000+07:00" numberOfRepairLaterDefects="0" repairOperator="c_admin" numberOfRepairLaterComponents="0" numberOfActiveComponents="0" numberOfActivePins="0" numberOfRepairedDefects="2" numberOfFalseCalledComponents="2"/>
    <ns1:TestXML name="3:hp1400">
        <ns1:IndictmentXML algorithm="u192036979" indictmentType="Wrong Polarity">
            <ns1:RepairActionXML repairOperator="c_admin" repairTime="2021-01-18T07:49:11.000+07:00" repairActionType="-" indictmentType="Wrong Polarity" comment="-" repairStatus="False Call"/>
            <ns1:ComponentXML packageId="192036979" partId="192036979" designator="3:hp1400"/>
        </ns1:IndictmentXML>
    </ns1:TestXML>
    <ns1:TestXML name="3:d506">
        <ns1:IndictmentXML algorithm="u192027714" indictmentType="Wrong Polarity">
            <ns1:RepairActionXML repairOperator="c_admin" repairTime="2021-01-18T07:49:11.000+07:00" repairActionType="-" indictmentType="Wrong Polarity" comment="-" repairStatus="False Call"/>
            <ns1:ComponentXML packageId="192027714" partId="192027714" designator="3:d506"/>
        </ns1:IndictmentXML>
    </ns1:TestXML>
    <ns1:TestXML name="3:j1201">
        <ns1:IndictmentXML algorithm="u192030753" indictmentType="Skewed">
            <ns1:RepairActionXML repairOperator="c_admin" repairTime="2021-01-18T07:49:17.000+07:00" repairActionType="-" indictmentType="Skewed" comment="-" repairStatus="Repaired"/>
            <ns1:ComponentXML packageId="192030753" partId="192030753" designator="3:j1201"/>
        </ns1:IndictmentXML>
    </ns1:TestXML>
    <ns1:TestXML name="3:u2101">
        <ns1:IndictmentXML algorithm="u192028597" indictmentType="Tombstoned">
            <ns1:RepairActionXML repairOperator="c_admin" repairTime="2021-01-18T07:49:24.000+07:00" repairActionType="-" indictmentType="Tombstoned" comment="-" repairStatus="Repaired"/>
            <ns1:ComponentXML packageId="192028597" partId="192028597" designator="3:u2101"/>
        </ns1:IndictmentXML>
    </ns1:TestXML>
</ns1:BoardTestXMLExport>
```

Code:

```
 foreach (string FILE_PATH in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"Test", "*.xml"))
                {

                    //Create xml reader
                    XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(FILE_PATH, new XmlReaderSettings());
                    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                    //Read xml to dataset
                    dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile);
                    //Pass empdetails table to datagridview datasource
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["BoardTestXMLExport"];
                    //Close xml reader
                    xmlFile.Close();
                    xmlFile.Close();

                }
```

Comment: Once you load the xml into a DataSet you can setup what to show in DataGridView. What's the problem here exactly?

Comment: I need to convert from xml file to txt with the information in the returned xml table.  But when loading xml into datagirdview, the information is not fully displayed with columns and rows.  If do not need to load data into the table is there any other solution to convert to txt?

Comment: *I need to convert from xml file to txt with the information in the returned xml table* → Well, xml is a readable text format, if you want another representation of the data, for example a CSV representation, then you need to parse the XML and format the result in a desired format. Loading into a DataSet is an easy way of loading data into a structured data structure which makes it easy to read and parse. Using XDocument is also an option to parse the xml.

Comment: Your question is explicitly asking about showing XML data in DataGridView but it's not quite clear what columns should be shown in DGV or if it's about exporting data in a CSV format or something, what columns should be used or what's the expected output here. Please share the expected output the same way that you shared the input.

Comment: And just as a side-note, there's no magical way of reading contents of many files as a bulk at once, you need to read them one by one, however you can make the reading faster by using Parallel for reading the content or getting the files by  EnumerateFiles and start reading tasks immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp\";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("filename", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("numberOfIndictedComponents", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("testerTestStartTime", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("testTime", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("repairStationId", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("testStatus", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("testerTestEndTime", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("imageId", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("serialNumber", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("assemblyRevision", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("boardType", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("boardRevision", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("testerName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("stage", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("algorithm", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("indictmentType", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("repairOperator", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("repairTime", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("repairActionType", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("comment", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("repairStatus", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("packageId", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("partId", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("designator", typeof(string));

            string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(FOLDER,"*.xml");
            foreach (string filename in filenames)
            {
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);
                XElement BoardTestXMLExport = doc.Root;
                XNamespace ns1 = BoardTestXMLExport.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("ns1");
 
                int numberOfIndictedComponents = (int)BoardTestXMLExport.Attribute("numberOfIndictedComponents");
                DateTime testerTestStartTime = (DateTime)BoardTestXMLExport.Attribute("testerTestStartTime");
                DateTime testTime = (DateTime)BoardTestXMLExport.Attribute("testTime");
                string repairStationId = (string)BoardTestXMLExport.Attribute("repairStationId");
                string testStatus = (string)BoardTestXMLExport.Attribute("testStatus");
                DateTime testerTestEndTime = (DateTime)BoardTestXMLExport.Attribute("testerTestEndTime");
                XElement BoardXML = BoardTestXMLExport.Element(ns1 + "BoardXML");
                int imageId = (int)BoardXML.Attribute("imageId");
                string serialNumber = (string)BoardXML.Attribute("serialNumber");
                string assemblyRevision = (string)BoardXML.Attribute("assemblyRevision");
                string boardType = (string)BoardXML.Attribute("boardType");
                string boardRevision = (string)BoardXML.Attribute("boardRevision");
                XElement StationXML = BoardTestXMLExport.Element(ns1 + "StationXML");
                string testerName = (string)StationXML.Attribute("testerName");
                string stage = (string)StationXML.Attribute("stage");
 
                foreach (XElement TestXML in doc.Descendants(ns1 + "TestXML"))
                {
                    DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                    newRow["filename"] = filename;
                    newRow["numberOfIndictedComponents"] = numberOfIndictedComponents;
                    newRow["testerTestStartTime"] = testerTestStartTime;
                    newRow["testTime"] = testTime;
                    newRow["repairStationId"] = repairStationId;
                    newRow["testStatus"] = testStatus;
                    newRow["testerTestEndTime"] = testerTestEndTime;
                    newRow["imageId"] = imageId;
                    newRow["serialNumber"] = serialNumber;
                    newRow["assemblyRevision"] = assemblyRevision;
                    newRow["boardType"] = boardType;
                    newRow["boardRevision"] = boardRevision;
                    newRow["boardType"] = boardType;
                    newRow["testerName"] = testerName;
                    newRow["stage"] = stage;
                        
                    newRow["name"] = (string)TestXML.Attribute("name");
                    XElement IndictmentXML = TestXML.Element(ns1 + "IndictmentXML");
                    newRow["algorithm"] = (string)IndictmentXML.Attribute("algorithm");
                    newRow["indictmentType"] = (string)IndictmentXML.Attribute("indictmentType");
                    XElement RepairActionXML = TestXML.Descendants(ns1 + "RepairActionXML").FirstOrDefault();
                    newRow["repairOperator"] = (string)RepairActionXML.Attribute("repairOperator");
                    newRow["repairTime"] = (DateTime)RepairActionXML.Attribute("repairTime");
                    newRow["repairActionType"] = (string)RepairActionXML.Attribute("repairActionType");
                    newRow["comment"] = (string)RepairActionXML.Attribute("comment");
                    newRow["repairStatus"] = (string)RepairActionXML.Attribute("repairStatus");
                    XElement ComponentXML = TestXML.Descendants(ns1 + "ComponentXML").FirstOrDefault();
                    newRow["packageId"] = (string)ComponentXML.Attribute("packageId");
                    newRow["partId"] = (string)ComponentXML.Attribute("partId");
                    newRow["designator"] = (string)ComponentXML.Attribute("designator");
                }
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The taget I wanna for this is to convert the xml file to txt format.  but I need to convert in bulk file and fast in the same directory.  instead of having to load each file and read and convert.  Do you have any suggestions for me?  Thanks very much

Comment: Xml linq is very fast.  I updated code to add additional columns and to read all the xml files in a folder.

Comment: hi @ jdweng, I've tried your code but the columns after fill data are blank. it cannot display any information. please check again

Comment: The code was working before latest changes.  So you must not be finding any files.  So check to make sure you are getting files.  See line : string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(FOLDER,"*.xml");